# Designing entity relations - theoretical or practical solutions?

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following issue with designing entity schemas.

Let's say that I've created a schema full of many-to-many relations, because it seemed like a reasonable choice at first, but during implementation those relations are not needed.

For example, theoretically each county can have many lakes and each lake can be located in many counties. But my database has no lakes crossing borders of the counties. **Is it still reasonable to use many-to-many relations?** It'll basically create a junction table that serves no need, because I can represent it with one-to-many relationships.

I have a geographical database that I intitially thought would contain a lot of many-to-many relations, but in practice such relations are needed only in a few tables.

Answer (score 2):

**First of all**: It's related to your Software [Functional Requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_requirement).

Your System Analysts should decide on that. And System Analysts should follow System Owners, End Users, and other Stakeholders within the organization.

If you write a project for an organization or company, you should ask them.

**Secondly**: In Database Design, if you have even few countries that can have common lake, you should use **many-to-many** relationship. The reason is **Extendability** of your project. I don't think many-to-many has a lot of difficulties in comparison with one-to-many.

**Thirdly**: If you have a **few** (seldom) countries that can have common lake, I think you can use this data modeling technique:

You can use **combination** of one-to-many and many-to-many.

1. Add primary key of `Country` as F.K to `Lake`. (for one-to-many relationship)
2. Add new table like `Country_Lakes` with F.Ks from `Country` and `Lake` (to many-to-many relationship)

How to detect the `Lake` type (common or not): If the F.K of `Country` in `Lake` is `NULL`, this `Lake` is common, you can get all Countries from `Country_Lakes`.

In this design, you have a little **Nullification**, but it happens seldom.

Answer (score 1):

If you might be using it, keep it. Creating many-to-many relationships afterwards is far more complicated.

If you won't ever use it, remove it.